# Average in dataframes with subsets of rows - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as the following:

```
Member Category Total
1001      1       5  
1001      2       4  
1001      3       9 
1003      1       7
1003      2       5
1003      3       2
1005      1       2 
1005      3       5
```

I need to get:

```
  Member Category Total  Average
    1001      1       5     0.27
    1001      2       4     0.22
    1001      3       9     0.5
    1003      1       7     0.5
    1003      2       5     0.35
    1003      3       2     0.15
    1005      1       2     0.28
    1005      3       5     0.72
```

That is, the average of totals for each member. For instance, the member 1001 has a total of 18, in which the category 1 represents 27% of the total. Therefore the average would be 0.27.

What I tried was:

```
average = []
for member in df[df["Member"].unique():
    total_member = df[df["Member"] == member]["Total"].sum()
    for category in df["Category"].unique():
        total_category = df[(df["Member"]==member) & (df["Category"]==category)]["Total"]
        average.append(total_category/total_member)

df["Average"] = average
```

However, not only does it not work, but since I have a very large amount of data, it is too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `sum` for divide by column `Total`:

```
df['Average'] = df['Total'] / df.groupby('Member')['Total'].transform('sum')
print (df)
   Member  Category  Total   Average
0    1001         1      5  0.277778
1    1001         2      4  0.222222
2    1001         3      9  0.500000
3    1003         1      7  0.500000
4    1003         2      5  0.357143
5    1003         3      2  0.142857
6    1005         1      2  0.285714
7    1005         3      5  0.714286
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('Member')['Total'].transform('sum'))
0    18
1    18
2    18
3    14
4    14
5    14
6     7
7     7
Name: Total, dtype: int64
```

Alternative solution:

```
df['Average'] = df['Total'] / df['Member'].map(df.groupby('Member')['Total'].sum())
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000

L = ['AV','DF','SD','RF','F','WW','FG','SX']
dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-02-20')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(N, 3)), columns=['Member','Category','Total'])
df = df.sort_values(['Member','Category']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
#Wen solution
In [395]: %timeit df.groupby('Member').Total.apply(lambda x : x/sum(x))
10 loops, best of 3: 31.2 ms per loop

In [396]: %timeit df['Total'] / df.groupby('Member')['Total'].transform('sum')
100 loops, best of 3: 5.11 ms per loop

#alternative a bit slowier solution
In [397]: %timeit df['Total'] / df['Member'].map(df.groupby('Member')['Total'].sum())
100 loops, best of 3: 9.92 ms per loop
```

Comment: Amazing answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
df['ave']=df.groupby('Member').Total.apply(lambda x : x/sum(x))
df
Out[318]: 
   Member  Category  Total       ave
0    1001         1      5  0.277778
1    1001         2      4  0.222222
2    1001         3      9  0.500000
3    1003         1      7  0.500000
4    1003         2      5  0.357143
5    1003         3      2  0.142857
6    1005         1      2  0.285714
7    1005         3      5  0.714286
```